# How to refactor a find | xargs one liner to a human readable code

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I've written an OCR wrapper batch & service script for tesseract and abbyyocr11 found here: https://github.com/deajan/pmOCR

The main function is a find command that passes it's arguments to xargs with -print0 in order to deal with special filenmames.
The find command became more and more complex and ended up as a VERY long one liner that becomes difficult to maintain:

```
find "$DIRECTORY_TO_PROCESS" -type f -iregex ".*\.$FILES_TO_PROCES" ! -name "$find_excludes" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'export file="{}"; function proceed { eval "\"'"$OCR_ENGINE_EXEC"'\" '"$OCR_ENGINE_INPUT_ARG"' \"$file\" '"$OCR_ENGINE_ARGS"' '"$OCR_ENGINE_OUTPUT_ARG"' \"${file%.*}'"$FILENAME_ADDITION""$FILENAME_SUFFIX$FILE_EXTENSION"'\" && if [ '"$_BATCH_RUN"' -eq 1 ] && [ '"$_SILENT"' -ne 1 ];then echo \"Processed $file\"; fi && echo -e \"$(date) - Processed $file\" >> '"$LOG_FILE"' && if [ '"$DELETE_ORIGINAL"' == \"yes\" ]; then rm -f \"$file\"; fi"; }; if [ "'$CHECK_PDF'" == "yes" ]; then if ! pdffonts "$file" 2>&1 | grep "yes" > /dev/null; then proceed; else echo "$(date) - Skipping file $file already containing text." >> '"$LOG_FILE"'; fi; else proceed; fi'
```

Is there a nicer way to pass the find results to a human readable function (without impacting too much speed) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Both answers are valid but I think the main thing here would be to fix the *horrible* script that this is being piped to. There's `eval` and a bunch of external environmental variables being directly inlined into code. There's excessive quoting from the use of `eval`. The conditionals can likely be simplified also.

Comment: I know... basically that's why I posted this as it became more and more awful. I'd like to have a find ... | function x where function x could be defined somewhere else in the script, but I don't find a way of doing this nicely.

Comment: It's not even clear that you *need* `eval`. Do any of those parameters include shell syntax, or are they just command names and options?

Comment: How did you get `eval` involved? What problem were you solving there? Also do **not** put `{}` into a script argument like that. It isn't safe. (Think about double quotes in the filename.) Always pass `{}` as an argument to bash and use a positional parameter in the script. How does that `$CHECK_PDF` logic work? You only want to avoid processing the files a second time when it is "yes" but other times you don't care about doing that?

Comment: I tend to use eval when I assemble commands from vars so I can log what I execute (not in this case indeed). Your remark on {} is justified.
The $CHECK_PDF logic is if to avoid reprocessing if CHECK_PDF=yes and pdffonts check is successful, and log skipped files only.

Comment: That's a habit you should break ASAP. Don't use `eval` just to avoid having to keep your log messages up-to-date with changes in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `find` altogether. It's easier in `bash` 4 (which I'll show here), but doable in `bash` 3.

```
proceed () {
  ...
}

shopt -s globstar

extensions=(pdf tif tiff jpg jpeg bmp pcx dcx)
for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
  for file in /some/path/**/*."$ext"; do
    [[ ! -f $file || $file = *_ocr.pdf ]] && continue
    # Rest of script here
  done
done
```

---

Prior to `bash` 4, you can write your own recursive function to descend through a directory hierarchy.

```
descend () {
    for fd in "$1"/*; do
        if [[ -d $fd ]]; then
            descend "$fd"
        elif [[ ! -f $fd || $fd != *."$ext" || $fd = *_ocr.pdf ]]; then
            continue
        else
            # Rest of script here
        fi
     done
 }

 for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
     descend /some/path "$ext"
 done
```

Comment: Seems a good solution. I'll have to run this on bash 3.2 (centos 5). The extension array will work i guess, what does bash 3 not handle please?

Comment: The `**` pattern, which lets you iterate over all the matching files recursively.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Last question, performance find vs for iterations ? Any clues (when having millions of files and directories) ?

Comment: That should be a bottleneck; in one case `find` iterates, in the other `bash`. Both are starting one new process each time to run your script.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `bash -c`. You are already committed to starting a new `bash` process for each file from the `find` command, so just save the code to a file and run that with

```
find "$DIRECTORY_TO_PROCESS" -type f -iregex ".*\.$FILES_TO_PROCES" \
     ! -name "$find_excludes" -print0 |
     xargs -0 -I {} bash script.bash {}
```

Comment: Works but I'd really like it to stay in the same file.

Comment: You could probably define and export the functions before calling `find`: `wrapper () { ... }; proceed () {...}; export -f proceed wrapper; find ... | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'wrapper {}'`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, create the script, then run find.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap cleanup EXIT
cleanup() { rm "$script"; }

script=$(mktemp)
cat <<'END' > "$script"
########################################################################
file="$1"

function proceed { 
    "$OCR_ENGINE_EXEC" "$OCR_ENGINE_INPUT_ARG" "$file" "$OCR_ENGINE_ARGS" "$OCR_ENGINE_OUTPUT_ARG" "${file%.*}$FILENAME_ADDITION$FILENAME_SUFFIX$FILE_EXTENSION"
    if [ "$_BATCH_RUN" -eq 1 ] && [ "$_SILENT" -ne 1 ]; then 
        echo "Processed $file"
    fi
    echo -e "$(date) - Processed $file" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    if [ "$DELETE_ORIGINAL" == "yes" ]; then 
        rm -f "$file"
    fi
}

if [ "$CHECK_PDF" == "yes" ]; then 
    if ! pdffonts "$file" 2>&1 | grep "yes" > /dev/null; then 
        proceed
    else 
        echo "$(date) - Skipping file $file already containing text." >> '"$LOG_FILE"'; 
    fi
else 
    proceed
fi
########################################################################
END

find "$DIRECTORY_TO_PROCESS" -type f \
                             -iregex ".*\.$FILES_TO_PROCES" \
                           ! -name "$find_excludes" \
                             -exec bash "$script" '{}' \;
```

The `'END'` of the heredoc is quoted, so the variables are not expanded until the script is actually executed.

Comment: Makes it human readable indeed, but still has a lot of doublequote / singlequotes. Any way to get the function "out of the find command" so it can be simplified and reused ?

Comment: You could probably avoid `find` altogether with an appropriate `for` loop, but it's not clear what that would look like without knowing the values of `$FILES_TO_PROCES` and `$find_excludes`.

Comment: Replacing both values would give something like:
find /somepath -type f -iregex ".*\.\(pdf\|tif\|tiff\|png\|jpg\|jpeg\|bmp\|pcx\|dcx\)" ! -name "*_ocr.pdf" -print0 | xargs [...]

Comment: Nothing there that `bash` can't handle natively (more cleanly in `bash` 4, but doable in older versions as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I finished using a while loop with a substituted find command, ie:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        if ! lsof -f -- "$file" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            if [ "$_BATCH_RUN" == true ]; then
                Logger "Preparing to process [$file]." "NOTICE"
            fi
            OCR "$file" "$fileExtension" "$ocrEngineArgs" "$csvHack"
        else
            if [ "$_BATCH_RUN" == true ]; then
                Logger "Cannot process file [$file] currently in use." "ALWAYS"
            else
                Logger "Deferring file [$file] currently being written to." "ALWAYS"
                kill -USR1 $SCRIPT_PID
            fi
        fi
    done < <(find "$directoryToProcess" -type f -iregex ".*\.$FILES_TO_PROCES" ! -name "$findExcludes" -and ! -wholename "$moveSuccessExclude" -and ! -wholename "$moveFailureExclude" -and ! -name "$failedFindExcludes" -print0)
```

The while loop reads every file from the find command in file variable.
Using -d $'\0' in while and -print0 in find command helps dealing with special filenames.